# atlas auth login returns i/o timeout

Tags: mongodb, post, cloud, mongodb-atlas

I simply installed the Atlas CLI following [these instructions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cli/stable/install-atlas-cli/) and I'm trying to login, but when I run `atlas auth login` I get the following error:

`Error: Post "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/private/unauth/account/device/authorize": dial tcp: lookup cloud.mongodb.com: i/o timeout`

My internet connection is working fine, and if I try to do a post request with curl to the link in the error description

```
$ curl -X POST https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/private/unauth/account/device/authorize
```

I get the following:

```
{"detail":"Unexpected error.","error":500,"errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","parameters":[],"reason":"Internal Server Error"}
```

I don't think Atlas is down, I can reach https://cloud.mongodb.com/, log in with my account and see my database, but I don't understand what's going on.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, when I run `atlas --version` I get

```
atlascli version: 1.10.0
git version: 949f87eeb5ce1e7b3e513cab59f44a23ee315e56
Go version: go1.20.6
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
```